# iOS 4.0 contentScaleFactor and scale - how to handle in 3.1.3?

Tags: iphone

I am tasked with making an app that works in iOS 4.0 work in 3.1.3 and 3.2 again. Mostly it is straightforward but the handling of the new API for scale and other situations where values must be passed/returned is hard.

respondsToSelector/performSelector takes care of nearly everything else.

Here's a simplified version of what is going on:

```
-(float)getImageScaleFactor 
{
  if([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale == 2.0)
      return kScaleFactorForRetinaDisplay;
  else
      return kScaleFactorForOlderDisplay;
}
```

scale isn't in iOS prior to 4.0.

Can anyone show a code sample that will work in all versions of iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use very similar code, but you're missing one important part: `respondsToSelector:`

```
if([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0f)
    return kScaleFactorForRetinaDisplay;
else
    return kScaleFactorForOlderDisplay;
```

Comment: Of course... facepalm moment. I have been working in an older Xcode with base SDK 3.1.3 to flag all the things to fix, and forgot that compiling those things is just fine once I move back to base SDK 4.1 - I just have to avoid calling them with respondsToSelector. What really bugs me though is that setting deployment target to 3.1.3 doesn't flag the problem areas the same way as switching to base SDK 3.1.3 does.